# AS3 how do you send vars to the parent constructor of an inherited class?

Tags: actionscript-3, inheritance

That title probably made no sense, so I'll try to explain.

Let's say I create a class in AS3, any class with some basic vars, and those vars are set through that classes constructor

so..

`var class = new basicClass(var1, var2);`

Now let's say I want to create a new class which inherits the basicClass's vars/methods etc, so new class has something like

`public class betterClass extends basicClass`

and maybe that also has some vars that are set via it's constructor.

Now what I'm confused about is, how do you set the parent classes (basicClass) vars or do anything through it's constructor by creating betterClass?

If basicClass has a constructor which expects values, then how do you set that up, by doing...

`var class2 = new betterClass(var3, var4)`

because `var3` and `var4` are for the constructor of betterClass, I don't see how an instance of `basicClass` is setup.

I know this is pretty basic stuff, it's just I've never needed to use inheritance before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have got BasicClass, its constructor may look like this:

```
public function BasicClass(var1:*, var2:*)
{
    //do some stuff with var1 and var2
}

//you can extend some metods too
public function niceFunction():void
{
    trace('Oh! Hello!');
}
```

Now you can create BetterClass:

```
public function BetterClass(var3:*, var4:*)
{
    super(var3, var4);
    //this calls constructor of BasicClass
}

override public function niceFunction():void
{
    super.niceFunction();
    trace('Nice to meet you.');
    //This will trace: Oh! Hello! Nice to meet you.
}
```

Comment: What if it's inherited twice? so let's say you had a evenBetterClass, what would super refer too? or is it just the closest parent?

Comment: It's always the next available super class in the inheritance chain, and that should generally be sufficient.  If you have to explicitly "jump" over one super class to the next, chances are your inheritance model is flawed. In other words: I would consider that a code smell.

Comment: ok but what I'm trying to setup is something like a root class of movement (handles positioning/movement), then a child from that called visual (which contains the visual element) and then a child from that of a personality class (handles what the thing actually is ,it's game logic etc), so how would I setup the personality class, but at the same time setup it's movement (root class), and obviously it's visual as well ?

Comment: This is a separate problem. It seems that you need kind of 'data model' class to store logic and a visual ('view') class. Visual class shouldn't inherit from data model, it should use it. This is OOP related problem: IS vs HAS (inheritance vs composition).

Comment: Thanks I thought it better to start a new question, as the initial question I had here was answered, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the parent class's constructor from your extending class using the 'super' keyword'

```
public betterClass(){
    super(constuctorParam1,constructorParam2);// this calls the constructor of the class this class extended
}
```

Here is more detailed info
http://ntt.cc/2009/07/26/beginning-actionscript-3-super-this-setter-getter.html

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you have different signatures

```
package {
  public class A {
    protected var _a:String, _b:String;
    public function A(a:String, b:String) {
      _a = a;
      _b = b;
    }
  }
}

package {
  public class B extends A {
    private var _c:Number;
    public function B(c:Number) {
      super('', '');
      _c = c;
    }
  }
}
```

You have to be aware of the different arguments and their meaning. Also, provide useful defaults if possible.

Just some additional input.